# temporary lack of access to the apache server - how to determine the cause

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

Every once in a while a page made available on the apache server is not available. After a few minutes everything is working (the party is often visited). How can I establish what this problem results from (how to read it from logs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start looking at /var/log/apache2/error.log [in debian world. possibly it's different location in settings of server/vhost ].

also enable [status page](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Monitoring_Apache_with_mod_status) and try to poll it automatically every say 30 sec and dump to disk - maybe your appache has limits for number of parallel connections it can handle and you run out of them?

install [munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) and start gathering statistics - maybe your machine swaps to death? surly monitoring tools will not help you when machine is dying but will show you trends.. you'll have some trace what happened just before the hiccup.

possibly you experience networking issues... does ssh / ping work when apache does not respond?

Comment: network is not rather problem, i try check i have max 2000 connection but maybe it is not enough.. how i can automatically save status page?

Comment: @m238 - try putting on cron every minute wget -O /var/log/apa`date +%s
` http://localhost/server-status  ; notice reverse apostrophe; this is temporary hack so you should clean up all apa* files after day or so and disable cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I think I deciphered what you are asking...

Try using Apache's [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) to see what it is doing.

In the httpd.conf file:

```
<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from YOUR.IP
</Location>
```

Restart apache and see what is happening. My guess is you are breaching the max clients limit.

Comment: it never happens me, it is rather strong machine 8 core, 24 GB RAM and I never see cpu (top command) more than 5%. But i believe users who told me that something like this happens. Is possibility to record everything what show server status?, sory for my English..